# Is Fly-By Topology for SATA possible?

Tags: sata

I have a single sata lane on host side. I want to connect dozens of hard disks to the lane using analog switches or multiplexers, instead of chainning multiplier chips (avoiding possible firmware and driver issue). At any time, only one disk is powered on and is connected to the lane with an analog switch.

My question is, is it possible to route a differential signal (for example, the tx pair from host) through the pins of an array of switches with a pair of 50ohm resistors at the end for impedence matching and avoiding reflection? The analog switches are simple on/off switches. For each switch, one side is connected to the "bus" lane. The other side is connected to the on-board sata connector, which connects to a disk via a cable.

Comment: I don't think you can just throw in a pair of 50 Ohm resistors for termination. That doesn't make sense because if it was *really* just a direct pass-through, the SATA receiver is already terminated at the far end. There's impedance matching of the traces themselves that likely has to be done and the impedance discontinuity of the switch. Might be best to try and work something out using SATA repeater ICs than regular old analog switches which probably don't have enough bandwidth anyways.

Comment: You are right. The impedance matching won't be that simple. I will go with 1:2 multiplexer ic. Not expensive. To connect to 2^n drives, I need 2^n - 1 mux chips to construct a binary tree. May be I could leave a output at leaf node for extension and put a redriver ic there to eliminate the signal attentuation. Thank you.

Comment: Does the host know how to handle a drive disappearing? What does it do if it has cached but uncommitted writes to that drive when it gets switched out? This sounds like a good way to corrupt data on hard drives.

Comment: For sure construct just ONE and see if it works before making a board with dozens and dozens of them. That alone will introduce issues due to the longer trace lengths.

Comment: @Hearth Hmm, yeah that's a good point. I had automatically assumed that the OP would only ever switch the drives while the system was powered down but I guess that might not be the case.

Comment: @Hearth the host is a linux system, the software will controll data flushing, then power down the spinning drive, switching to another one. The idea is, with a ssd cache (all directories and some documents and thumbnails for media ), the access to hard disk is minimized. Of course the accessability is very limited, but we can use less than 20W power supply to support a cool and silent system with dozens of disks. As a metaphor, it is using the disk to mimic tape. Suitable for storing archives for personal data without much need for concurrency.